# How to sum two non-integer numbers in LaTeX?

Tags: calculations

Here is the sample format of non-integers number

```
12.5+13.8=26.3
```

Comment: With LuaLaTeX: `\directlua{tex.sprint(12.5+13.8)}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}

$12.5+13.8 = \fpeval{12.5+13.8} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: File `xfp.sty' not found. @Herbert

Comment: Also, curious: what does it say for `\fpeval{0.1+0.2}`?

Comment: @BikiTeron: install it. `xfp` is part of `l3packages`: http://ctan.org/pkg/xfp

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: feel free to test it ... ;-)

Comment: @Herbert Unfortunately, I wasn't able to install it. I got `xfp.{dtx,ins}` but then I got `Package xfpu Error: Support package l3kernel too old`. Gave up at this point. Nevermind, just idle curiosity about floating-point. Will find out some day when I upgrade my TeX distribution :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: you have to update the three "package bundles" `l3kernel`,  `l3experimental` and `l3packages` or simply update these ones if they are already installed.

Comment: command to install new packages in texlive, open your terminal window as root and type as shown "tlmgr install xfp" without quotes @ShreevatsaR